# How to upload file to aws s3 with input file?

Tags: node.js, file, amazon-s3, buffer

Let's suppose get `file` in below server function from client `input`.

console.log(file) is

```
{
  filename: '20200608_110520.jpg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
}
```

And now I want to upload this file to aws s3. I confused what above file is. The error message `file` should one of `type string`, `an instsance of Buffer`, `ArrayBuffer`. But above is just an object. right? What is that? is it `Blob` ? or `File` ? or just an `Object`? How can I transform this to proper one?

```
const imageUpload = async (file) => {
  ...
  const s3 = new AWS.S3()
  
  const params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: 'CoolFileName',
    Body: file,
  }

  const { Location, Key } = await s3.upload(params).promise()

  // TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: 
  // The first argument must be of type string or 
  // an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array 
  // or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object** 

}
```

**I'm using GraphQL... I think it make this complicated....**

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I simply use `createReadStream()`

```
const imageUpload = async (file) => {
  ...
  const s3 = new AWS.S3()
  const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file

  const params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: 'CoolFileName',
    Body: createReadStream(),
  }

  const { Location, Key } = await s3.upload(params).promise()


}
```